# freeradius module failing to launch

Tags: mysql, module, shared-libraries, radius, freeradius

I have this problem with freeradius module. 
I'm trying to add my custom module, but after I launch radius server in debug mode it shows me this error:

```
/usr/local/etc/raddb/modules/m2[2]: Failed to link to module 'rlm_m2': libmysql.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 
/usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default[224]: Failed to load module "m2".
/usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default[69]: Errors parsing authorize section.
```

My system is Ubuntu 12, all mysql packages are installed correctly(there does exist libmysql.so.16 in usr/lib/mysql) freeradius runs smoothly with default parameters and so on. I really don't have an idea what exactly can't find this mysql library or  how to show it to it.

Comment: If you need more info, just ask, I'm just not even sure what could help here

Answer (score 0):

Try compile like this:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/mysql rlm_m2.c -o rlm_m2 -lmysqlclient -lnsl -lm -lz\
    -L/usr/lib/mysql -L/usr/lib/mysql -L/usr/lib64/mysql
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `-L` options go _before_ the `-l` ones?